# Determine which version of Silverlight an assembly is built under

Tags: silverlight, compiler-construction, assemblies, version

I have a Silverlight project in which I compile to both Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3 using the instructions [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/sxs-sl2-sl3-building/) which imports MSBuild targets into the csproj file from two seperate locations holding Silverlight 2 and 3 targets respectively.

The build/compilation seems to work, producing two different files, but I was wondering if (and how) I can determine which compiler-version produced a specific assembly. To be clear, I'm not looking for the version of the assembly it self, rather the version of the compiler which produced it (I'm assuming that it is registered somewhere in the assembly for loading and verification purposes by the runtime)

Can I get this information (Reflector, Ildasm?), I just wanted to do a simple verification that the build process used the two different versions as intended.

Comment: Why not just build to Silverlight 3?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: This may be my own ignorance, but we have a library we would like to offer to both SL2 and SL3 projects. Wouldn't building to SL3 create a backwards compatibility problem when including the SL3 library in a SL2 project?

Comment: How many SL2 projects do you think will be around these days is my point.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I see your point we would just like to target as large an audience as possible and we ourselves had a SL2 project going untill only a few weeks ago. Put the non-changing compiler and the non-changing version numbers in your reply (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906595/determine-which-version-of-silverlight-an-assembly-is-built-under/1907699#1907699) is exactly what I needed to see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the version of compiler.  The compiler hasn't changed between SL2 and 3, both use the version 3 compiler.  What makes SL2 differ from SL3 are the libraries that are referenced.

Unfortunately the SL3 libraries are still numbered 2.0.5.0 which makes a determination rather awkward.

Comment: Was unaware of the non-changing compiler. Thanks, Anthony